# WSO2 Identity Server SSO integrated with spring-security

Tags: authentication, wso2, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

Now I'm trying to transform two website systems to SSO authentication using WSO2 Identity Server ,these two systems have
their own authentication,one of them use spring-security to control the url Authorities,i've just cut the spring-security intercept and successfully implement SSO authentication，now I wonder if I can implement SSO integrated with spring-security ,what confuse me is the two different systems have different User entity and their own authorization strategy,should I change the struct of them to the same now ?

Answer (score 0):

you can create roles of both the applications in Identity server and assign them to an user. For example, If a user has role as ADMIN in application1 and USER in application2, you can assign both the roles to the same user in ID server.

I think Spring security authentications used in your applications won't be affected because you will use only Principal values to authenticate user.